# Rand in matrix value

Tags: c, matrix, random

I am doing a code that needs to generate a random matrix, save it in a `.txt` and do something with it. The matrix needs to change in dimension and I think the way I declared it is the way that will allow me to deallocate and then allocate it again (if not please let me know).

My problem is the random number generator doesn't work, it saves one number in the file and if I print it it gives two different outputs. It's probably because I am not declaring the matrix well or giving it the value accordingly.

I will leave a picture of the three different outputs it creates, only one makes sense given the range I put `rand` to work with (1-9).

I believe the problem is in the usage of the matrix. Is the matrix a pointer in my code? When would I use `*` or `&` with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    int nmatrix=3;
    int nmax=nmatrix;
    int number, cout, count, count2, i, j, k, p;
    srand(time(NULL));
    //int C[nmatrix][nmatrix];
    //int (*B)[nmatrix][nmatrix] = malloc(nmatrix * nmatrix * sizeof(int));
    float **a = malloc(nmatrix * sizeof(float *));
    for (p = 0; p < nmatrix; p++) { 
        a[p]=malloc(nmatrix * sizeof(int));
    }
    while(nmatrix<=nmax){
        // Creation of Matrix
        f = fopen("matrix.txt", "w");
        for(count = 0; count < nmatrix; count ++){
            for(count2 = 0; count2 < nmatrix; count2 ++){
                a[count][count2]= (rand()%8)+1;
                fprintf(f, "%s%d ", " ", a[count][count2]);
                printf(" A1:%d, A2:%d \n", a[count][count2], a[count][count2]);
            }
            fprintf(f, "%s\n", " ");
        }
        fclose(f);
        nmatrix=nmatrix+1;
        /*More code*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `a[p]=malloc(nmatrix * sizeof(int));` is pretty suspicious, as `a` is a `float**` - on second look, you seem to want to have `a` be an `int**`, as you are never using any `float` values

Comment: You are right, corrected `int` so that it is `float` but the problem persists.

Comment: (see edit to my previous comment), `fprintf(f, "%s%d ", " ", a[count][count2]);` invokes *undefined behavior* as `a[count][count2]` returns a `float` but you are telling `fprintf` to treat it as an `int`

Comment: You're printing `float` values with an `int` conversion specification (`%d` instead of `%f`).

Comment: Aside: `fprintf(f, "%s\n", " ");` is crude, and why do you need a space before a newline?

Comment: Oh my god it was something so small! Thank you very much! I had put `%d` at the beginning when I had the matrix specified as `int` but then realized that for what I needed it had to be `float`. Forgot to change the rest. Thank you!

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: your question states that you want matrix values from 1...9.  However, this statement: `a[count][count2]= (rand()%8)+1;` will result in matrix values from 1...8.   Suggest using: `a[count][count2]= (rand()%9)+1;`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`  and then to motivate you to actually fix the warnings, also use: `-Werror`

Comment: the function: `malloc()` is prototyped in `stdlib.h` so no need to include the header file: `malloc.h`.  It is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  I.E. `string.h`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  Names like `p` are meaningless, even in the current context.  3) names should be unique and not just by a single character.  so names like `count` and `count2` are more confusing than informative.

Comment: 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  the posted code contains the 'magic' number 3.  The code should use a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.